# Why aren't new, flat buttons appearing in my Bootstrap 4 page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please help me understand why I am seeing old-fashion, gradient buttons in what is supposed to be a Bootstrap 4, flat-button page?

Here is the page markup: http://jsbin.com/zimatemiya/edit?html,css,output (button is beneath navbar)

I should be seeing the one-colour, blue, "primary" button as at http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/

It is the product of a WordPress theme I am building using Bootstrap 4.
So WordPress is including some files in there.
I'm not sure what's wrong.
Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='braincloud-style-css'  href='http://www.braincloudhq.com/wp-content/themes/braincloud/style.css?ver=4.4.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Something in here is mucking with the button CSS. Removing it causes the button to be shown in Bootstrap 4 style.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

Currently that style is coming from this CSS style

```
button {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Reset that to `box-shadow: none`